# My countdown program is not working well

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a program that when it starts, a GUI window appears, and there is a countdown from 5 to 0.

This is the code:

```
number=5
from tkinter import *
class application(Frame):
  def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widget()
  def create_widget(self):
    global number
    self.lbl1=Label(self, text=number)
    self.lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
    for I in range(5):
       number=number-1    #the countdown
       root.after(1000, self.update)
  def update(self):
    global number
    self.lbl1.configure(text=number)
```

When the program starts, the number 5 appears, and suddenly turns to 0.

Can someone tell me what is the problem in my code?

Comment: There is no problem. Your `for` loop runs very quickly (within milliseconds) that you don't actually see the label updating.

Comment: You have a class.  Why are you using a global variable?

Comment: You should be decreasing `number` in your `update` method. You shouldn't have the `for` loop at all. Instead, call `root.after(1000, self.update)` once within `create_widget` and once within `update` (so that each `update` will trigger a new `update` one second later.) Alternatively, you could call `after` in a `for` loop, as you're doing now (decreasing `number` still needs to move into `update`), but in each call, increase the amount of time that it'll wait for by 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

`root.after(1000, self.update)` does not do the waiting itself.  It puts `self.update` in a queue that the main loop checks later.  You put `self.update` in a queue and then continue with the loop.  You can set `I` to each number from `1` to `5` before the `.after(...)` call that you made when `I` was zero takes effect.  Instead of setting `I` in the `create_widget()` loop, put it in `update()`:

```
def create_widget(self):
    ...
    self.number = number
    root.after(1000, self.update)
def update(self):
    self.lbl1.configure(text=self.number)
    self.number -= 1
    if self.number:
        root.after(1000, self.update)
```

Answer (score 1):

You create 5 update callbacks to be executed in 1 second.  All 5 trigger and update to the final value of number, which is 0.  Put print(number) in the callback to see.

You need to create 1 callback and conditionally create another in the update function. The following runs from an IDLE editor or in a terminal with python -m filename.py

```
from tkinter import *

class application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, number):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.number = number
        self.grid()
        self.create_widget()
    def create_widget(self):
        self.lbl1 = Label(self, text=self.number)
        self.lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.master.after(1000, self.update)
    def update(self):
        if self.number:
            self.number -= 1
            self.lbl1.configure(text=self.number)
            self.master.after(1000, self.update)

root = Tk()
number=5
app = application(root, number)
```

There are many other examples of correct use of root.after on SO.